# how to reduce the key number used in symmetric encryption

Tags: encryption-symmetric, symmetric, symmetric-difference

We know the number of key used in symmetric encryption is n(n-1)/2. Is there a way to reduce the number of keys used in the communication?

Let’s say that if there are 1000 students wants to communicate with each other using symmetric encryption, according to the n(n-1)/2 ,  the total keys is 499500. Is there a way to reduce the key used during this story?

This question has been struggled me for two weeks I have tried Google and textbook but with no luck on finding the possible answers. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to use Asymmetric encryption, each student would have one key pair each and be able to communicate with any other student.

Hope this helps.